# How do I prevent AppleScript from using short numbers?

Tags: applescript

So AppleScript by default uses the exponential notation of numbers - for example, 2.99E+68.
How do I prevent that from happening? I want the number written out as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An AppleScript function `convertNumberToString` is provided by Apple.

[Mac Automation Scripting Guide: Manipulating Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateNumbers.html)

> #### Converting a Long Number to a String
>
> In AppleScript, long numeric values are displayed in scientific notation. For example, `1234000000` is displayed by a script as `1.234E+9`. When this value is coerced to a string, it becomes: `"1.234E+9"`. The handler in Listing 20-3 converts a number, regardless of length, to a string of numeric characters instead of a numeric string in scientific notation.
>
> ```
> on convertNumberToString(theNumber)
>     set theNumberString to theNumber as string
>     set theOffset to offset of "E" in theNumberString
>     if theOffset = 0 then return theNumberString
>     set thePrefix to text 1 thru (theOffset - 1) of theNumberString
>     set theConvertedNumberPrefix to ""
>     if thePrefix begins with "-" then
>         set theConvertedNumberPrefix to "-"
>         if thePrefix = "-" then
>             set thePrefix to ""
>         else
>             set thePrefix to text 2 thru -1 of thePrefix
>         end if
>     end if
>     set theDecimalAdjustment to (text (theOffset + 1) thru -1 of theNumberString) as number
>     set isNegativeDecimalAdjustment to theDecimalAdjustment is less than 0
>     if isNegativeDecimalAdjustment then
>         set thePrefix to (reverse of (characters of thePrefix)) as string
>         set theDecimalAdjustment to -theDecimalAdjustment
>     end if
>     set theDecimalOffset to offset of "." in thePrefix
>     if theDecimalOffset = 0 then
>         set theFirstPart to ""
>     else
>         set theFirstPart to text 1 thru (theDecimalOffset - 1) of thePrefix
>     end if
>     set theSecondPart to text (theDecimalOffset + 1) thru -1 of thePrefix
>     set theConvertedNumber to theFirstPart
>     set theRepeatCount to theDecimalAdjustment
>     if (length of theSecondPart) is greater than theRepeatCount then set theRepeatCount to length of theSecondPart
>     repeat with a from 1 to theRepeatCount
>         try
>             set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & character a of theSecondPart
>         on error
>             set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & "0"
>         end try
>         if a = theDecimalAdjustment and a is not equal to (length of theSecondPart) then set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & "."
>     end repeat     if theConvertedNumber ends with "." then set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & "0"
>     if isNegativeDecimalAdjustment then set theConvertedNumber to (reverse of (characters of theConvertedNumber)) as string
>     return theConvertedNumberPrefix & theConvertedNumber
> end convertNumberToString
> ```

Comment: just tobe sure, will this work even when I need to work with it as a number afterwards?

Comment: @Prokop If you want to work with it as a number, just keep it as the original number and work with that until you want to output it as a string.

Comment: a'ight, thanks. mind checking out my other unanswered question as well?

Answer (score 5):

You can coerce the number to a unit of measurement and then into a string, like this:

```
1.2345E+9 as inches as string
```

which will return `"1234500000"`.

You can use any unit of measurement, such as kilograms, cubic centimetres, gallons, degrees Kelvin etc.

Comment: What does inches etc add to the expression? I don't see any inch symbol `"` and when I myself test with different units the result is the same, independently of the unit.

Comment: @d-b Yes, that's correct.  There's no symbol for any of these units.  They're class object specifiers used for conversions.  I chose `inches` as it has the fewest letters, but isn't otherwise special in and of itself.  However, the act of coercing between types using a measurement unit class as an intermediary _is_ special.  As for _why_ this would be or should be the case, I don't know. It may not be a feature that was intended to be part of AppleScript, but rather a bug whose consequences are advantageous rather than detrimental (it wouldn't be the only example of such a phenomenon).