# Applescript & Javascript to get number from chrome and give a total

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, javascript, javascript-automation

I'm trying do get every totals from an internal webpage and get the total.

for getting a single result I wrote this :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 1 of window 1 to set orderTotal to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].innerHTML;"
end tell
```

the output on this example is :

```
"<td>1,200.00</td><td>JPY</td>"
```

(PS the currency is not always the same)

for getting every value this work

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 1 of window 1 to set r to execute javascript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('total');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;"
end tell
 return r
```

which give me something like this :

```
"<td>4,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>3,800.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", missing value, missing value, missing
```

I would like to clear the text and do a total,

Tried this for clearing the values, but obviously not working :

```
set theText to Unicode text
property leftEdge1 : "<td>"
property rightEdge1 : "</td>"
try
    set saveTID to text item delimiters
    set text item delimiters to leftEdge1
    set classValue to text item 2 of r
    set text item delimiters to rightEdge1
    set singleValue to text item 1 of classValue
    set text item delimiters to saveTID
    singleValue
end try
```

and for the total I'm not sure yet how to proceed.

Comment: 1. What is the URL of the web page? 2. The line following "which give me something like this :" appears to be missing the word "value" as it ends in "missing" instead of "missing value", so which is it? 3. Since `r` contains the contents of an `array` it should probably be treated as a `list` and you need to _loop_ through it with a `repeat` _statement_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that absence of the actual URL and what appears to be incomplete output shows in the OP the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* defines `r` as a `list` and sums its numeric values.

```
set r to {"<td>4,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>3,800.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", "<td>5,000.00</td><td>JPY</td>", missing value, missing value, missing value}

set theText to Unicode text
property leftEdge1 : "<td>"
property rightEdge1 : "</td>"
set totalValue to 0

repeat with i from 1 to count r
    try
        set saveTID to text item delimiters
        set text item delimiters to leftEdge1
        set classValue to text item 2 of item i of r
        set text item delimiters to rightEdge1
        set singleValue to text item 1 of classValue
        set text item delimiters to saveTID
        set totalValue to totalValue + singleValue
    end try
end repeat

log totalValue

-- Result:
-- 42800
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any other *error handling* then what's shown and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: @Low Risk, While the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ works to return an _integer_, keep in mind that if not ending in `.00` the output will be in scientific notation. So you'll want to have a look at [Mac Automation Scripting Guide: Manipulating Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateNumbers.html) and there is also a simple way to coerce to a _numeric string_ in [an answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304371/how-do-i-prevent-applescript-from-using-short-numbers).